# What are some good GUI binary viewers/editors?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, editor, binary

What are some GUI applications that will let me view and edit binary files (executables, images, etc.).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- [**GHEX** [image: Install ghex]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ghex)

  [image]
- [**LFHEX** [image: Install lfhex]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lfhex)

  [image]
- **[WXHEXEDITOR](http://wxhexeditor.sourceforge.net/)**

  [image]
- **[VELES](https://veles.io)** (github, not developed now, nice 3D visualizations, full featured for analyzing of unknown data structures with support for png, zip and other)

  [image: veles example screenshot]

Comment: GHex is a reasonable viewer, but it's a terrible editor. Selecting a range of bytes was really awkward. Haven't tried the others. Okteta from one of the other answers worked well for me.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using KDE, [Okteta](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/okteta) is the way to go.

[image: Screenshot of Okteta]

Comment: +1: okteta seems much better than ghex, and the image posted it's helpful to gain proper usage in the many options available

Comment: Okteta runs OK under Ubuntu 19.04 (GNOME).

Answer (score 4):

Try [**GHex**](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Ghex)

```
sudo apt-get install ghex
```

From the app's [Github page](https://github.com/GNOME/ghex):

> GHex is a hex editor for the GNOME desktop.
>
> GHex can load raw data from binary files and display them for editing in the
>   traditional hex editor view. The display is split in two columns, with
>   hexadecimal values in one column and the ASCII representation in the other.
>   A useful tool for working with raw data.

Answer (score 2):

[sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is a good choice and it is multi purpose editor.

[image]