# how to open a program generated binary file?

Tags: c

i have implemented a c program where raw packets are received from the network and saved in a binary file. Thing is i cant open that binary file. i tried opening it using terminal,but i am getting permission denied.

I used

```
sudo ./sniff_data.bin
```

and its displaying

```
sudo: ./sniff_data.bin: command not found
```

Comment: If you're getting packets from some sort of sniffer it is probably running as root, and the data probably needs appropriate permissions set before you can read it.

Comment: @Rinzwind, i have added the commands which was used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding

```
sudo ./sniff_data.bin
```

A bin file is NOT an executable. You need software that can open a BIN file to view the BIN file.

What you want is probably

```
sudo hexdump sniff_data.bin
```

Another method:

```
sudo strings sniff_data.bin
```

This will show all the text strings inside the file.

---

For graphical methods viewing binaries see: [What are some good GUI binary viewers/editors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19479/what-are-some-good-gui-binary-viewers-editors)

Comment: oh alright thanks a lot :) . but cant i view the file without using the terminal?

Comment: if you want a graphical method see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19479/what-are-some-good-gui-binary-viewers-editors ;)