# How do I edit the binary or hexadecimal data of a file in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor, binary

Disclaimer: This is not the same as [What are some good GUI binary viewers/editors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19479/what-are-some-good-gui-binary-viewers-editors).

How do I edit the binary data of a file in a gedit like editor? Eg:

```
00001010101010010101
```

And how do I edit the hexadecimal data of a file in a gedit like editor? eg:

```
91021AF9B
```

I do not want one editor with both. I want two different editors.

I have looked a GHex and it is not what I want.

Comment: Look into **Bless** hex editor (for GNOME) or **ncurses-hexedit**, **hexer**,  or **hexcurse** (for console)

Comment: Thanks Nick. Bless looks good, but from what I can make out, hexedit is only for Windows?

Comment: `bless`, `hexedit`, `ncurses-hexedit`, `hexer`, and `hexcurse` are the names of packages  available in the Ubuntu software repositories. To install any of them, open a terminal window (alt--ctrl-T) and type `sudo apt install bless` (replacing `bless` with the name of your desired program)

Comment: `wxhexeditor` might be another option with a GUI interface

Comment: Wow there is a lot of hex editors. What about binary?

Comment: You know, you could always use vim for pretty much everything http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_hex_editing and http://usevim.com/2012/06/20/vim-binary-files/ and finally http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/343/how-to-edit-binary-files-with-vim

Comment: Thanks you guys. Could someone formulate these into a answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use vim which should already be installed.

Just to make sure, go ahead and install vim:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Now, use the vim command `:%! xxd -b` to edit binary like in this example:

```
vim /path/to/filename
```

**note: you can drag and drop the file into the terminal to automatically fill in the path for you**

FYI, the `:%! command` prefix allows you to pipe the current file's contents to command's stdin, and replaces the file's contents with command's stdout. `xxd` is a linux command.

Once the file is open, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then type `:%! xxd -b` and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can add the flag `-g4` to group the bits into 32 bit packets like `:%! xxd -b -g4`

[image]

For hex edit, use the vim command `:%! xxd` instead or `:%! xxd -g4`

[image: d]

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then <kbd>i</kbd> for "INSERT" mode which allows you to edit.

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then type `:w` followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file.

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then type `:q` followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then type `:q!` followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to exit the file.

Vim takes some getting used to but is really great once you take the time to learn how it works.

Additionally, vim allows you to edit just about anything including sqlite and all kinds of other stuff.

Also, when you convert a binary to hex and then edit, I think you may need to convert back to binary by using `:%! xxd -r` command [as described here.](http://usevim.com/2012/06/20/vim-binary-files/)

[More info can be found at the official wiki by clicking here.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hex_dump)

Here is a similar post:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282215/how-to-view-a-binary-file/282220

[Click here for more info on editing your .vimrc file to allow some related commands.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_hex_editing)

---

A very similar editor is `bvi`. Run the following command to install:

```
sudo apt-get install bvi
```

[Click here for more info.](http://bvi.sourceforge.net/edit.html)