# How to open the files with the extension (".so")

Tags: scripts

How to open the files with the extension (".so") like libphpcpp.so and ("ELF") format file in editor for editing?

Comment: The .so files are dynamic libraries, are you sure you need to open them in editor?

Comment: probably with Hex Editor like [Bless](https://launchpad.net/bless) but if you change the files that are not meant to be changed, then *things* can happen

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit the binary or hexadecimal data of a file in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786658/how-do-i-edit-the-binary-or-hexadecimal-data-of-a-file-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

.so files are "Shared Libraries" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries), they are binary-files meant to be dynamically linked to an executable and as such are unusable on their own.

A Library is a collection of related functions and *reusable resources* to be used by software applications. Shared-libraries are linked at runtime (*dynamic linking)* as opposed to compile-time hence their name.

If you want to open a shared-library file, you would open it like any other binary file -- with a hex-editor (also called a *binary-editor*). There are several hex-editors in the standard repositories such as GHex (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ghex) or Bless (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/bless). The same can be done for ELF executables.

You can install either of them with the following command(s):

```
sudo apt install ghex
```

or

```
sudo apt install bless
```

But bear in mind though, shared-objects (.so files) are binary files and therefore aren't meant to be edited manually; you might be able to edit a few strings or values with a hex-editor but you won't be able to do much since they are unusable on their own.

Answer (score 0):

The files with `.so` xtension are compiled libraries. The `elf` format is compiled sourcecode. I do not think you want to edit this one, rather edit the sourcecode of a library and then compile it. See [these docs](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) for refrence. it covers idea behind them, compilation, installation and usage of static libraries.